# How to delete a specific node in an ARKit sceneView

Tags: ios, arkit

I have a lot of nodes in my scene view including the standard "focus square" (the node that helps the user place an object and that lays on the surface as the user moves the phone). I want to remove all of them except for that one.

```
class FocusSquare: SCNNode {
    // MARK: - Types

    enum State: Equatable {
        case initializing
        case detecting(hitTestResult: ARHitTestResult, camera: ARCamera?)
    }

    ...
    // Find code here: https://github.com/BlackMirrorz/ARKitWorldMaps/tree/c7ea837006e26ec7d8542ad2d3c417d5fd3910d5/CloudCube/CloudCube/Apple%20Focus%20Square
}
```

This is how I remove all the nodes except for the focus square:

```
sceneView.scene.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes { (node, stop) in
    if let node = node as? FocusSquare {
        print("should not remove node") // fired once, however it still gets deleted
    } else {
        node.removeFromParentNode()
    }
}
```

However, this does remove the focus square as well even though I am checking for the node class. Why can't I delete a specific node?

I think the problem is that removing nodes here doesn't work like views. There's no "hierarchy" for how nodes are added in the scene view. I'm not sure though. This is how the focus square is added to the view:

```
public func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async { self.updateFocusSquare() }
}

func updateFocusSquare() {
    var screenCenter: CGPoint {
        let bounds = self.sceneView.bounds
        return CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
    }

    if let camera = self.augmentedRealitySession.currentFrame?.camera,
        case .normal = camera.trackingState,
        let result = self.sceneView.smartHitTest(screenCenter) {
        updateQueue.async {
            if self.canDisplayFocusSquare {
                self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(self.focusSquare)
                self.focusSquare.state = .detecting(hitTestResult: result, camera: camera)
            }
        }

    } else {
        updateQueue.async {
            if self.canDisplayFocusSquare {
                self.focusSquare.state = .initializing
                self.sceneView.pointOfView?.addChildNode(self.focusSquare)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to find the focus square, I'm actually trying to find my other custom node class:

```
sceneView.scene.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes { (node, stop) in
    if node is TranslationNode {
        node.removeFromParentNode()
    }
}
```

This works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a big expert on SceneKit, but if the FocusSquare is a subnode of another node then, this (FocusSquare parent) could have been removed during the enumeration leading to the removal of the FocusSquare as well.

Whould adding the FocusSquare to the rootNode solve it?

Hope this answer helped.